# More that one logical-name for database in parameter file (.pf)?

Tags: configuration, database-connection, progress-4gl, openedge

I have a parameter file (.pf) with different databases to connect. The databases have multiple aliases therefore I want to set the logical names of each database.

```
-db physical_database_name
-ld [Logical name/alias]
- [...]
```

When I set more `-ld` parameters than one, it takes only the last one.
How is it possible to set more than one alias in the Parameter file (.pf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional aliases can only be set through code.

What you could do is to use the -param Startup Parameter.

`-param dbname1=alias1,alias2|dbname2=alias3,alias4`

And process this string based SESSION:PARAMETER in your startup procedure.

Comment: In the parameter file, if I add a database twice with different aliases, is there any disadvantage?